# simpleDateformat not parsing when second is included

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am getting time in a particular format which I want to convert to another format. The below code snippet was taken from one of the stack overflow answers.

```
SimpleDateFormat origDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Date retrivedDate = origDateFormat.parse(origFormat);
return newDateFormat.format(retrivedDate);
```

This code format is working as long as my input date is of the following format: `22/08/2015 14:23`.
But when i try with seconds, i get the error:

> Unparseable date: "06/03/2019 14:17:25"

```
SimpleDateFormat origDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date retrivedDate = origDateFormat.parse(origFormat);
return newDateFormat.format(retrivedDate);
```

Comment: I'm able to parse `"06/03/2019 14:17:25"` using the second code snippet posted above.

Comment: @ MaruthiAdithya - no, SS is the format for milliseconds

Comment: You might wanna show more of your code, as your provided code works fine

Comment: I am trying to parse this date from a csv file, so input to this function is a string format of that particular time, other parts of code is pretty much straight forward

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: And please, what was your question? Asking because it’s not clear to me. On my computer your second snippet works with `"06/03/2019 14:17:25"`.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-)) the javadoc of `parse()` method and this is what it says:

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date.
>   The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

So, as per the documentation, you can parse `06/03/2019 14:17:25` dates with both `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` and `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` date formats. If you parse with the format that doesn't contain seconds then it will ignore the second part. Below is the working code:

```
String date = "06/03/2019 14:17:25";
SimpleDateFormat mmDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat ssDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

System.out.println(mmDateFormat.parse(date));
System.out.println(ssDateFormat.parse(date));
```

Below are the outputs:

```
Wed Mar 06 14:17:00 GMT 2019
Wed Mar 06 14:17:25 GMT 2019
```

Comment: Why are you using JDK 7 documentation?

Comment: Does appending a AM/PM to this date make a difference when parsing, example: 06/03/2019 2:17:35 PM

Comment: @Aarika you need to use `hh` instead of `HH` for 12 hour time format.

Comment: @uneq95 this doesn't justify the error but this explains why the error could be a false alarm and why it should not happen.